# 'StartIndex cannot be less than zero.' when trying to load a form in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have recently made some changes to one of the subs within a form of my vb project and I am now getting an error whilst attempting to load the form. I have little idea what `start index` or `Parameter name` are with relation to a form, so don't where to start looking to solve this issue. Here is the error message I get:

```
An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex
```

The Sub that I have made changes to is the last sub in the code below called `TextBox1changed_textchanged`. I have added all but the last 5 lines as to limit the characters that can be put into the text box. This new code is edited from another forum page so I assume it should work correctly, but I can't be sure as the form will no longer run.

```
Public Class frmAddQuantity

Private Sub frmFieldMaster_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    cmbStateRateSumRatio.Items.Clear()
    cmbStateRateSumRatio.Items.Insert(0, "State")
    cmbStateRateSumRatio.Items.Insert(1, "Rate")
    cmbStateRateSumRatio.Items.Insert(2, "Sum")
    cmbStateRateSumRatio.Items.Insert(3, "Ratio")


End Sub

Private Sub bttAddQUAtoDatabase_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bttAddQUAtoDatabase.Click

    AddQuantity("'" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & cmbStateRateSumRatio.Text & "'")

    InitialiseAll()
    frmFieldMaster.InitialiseNewParameter()
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    If TextBox2.Text <> "Enter SI Units" Then
        If cmbStateRateSumRatio.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            bttAddQUAtoDatabase.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmbStateRateSumRatio_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbStateRateSumRatio.SelectedIndexChanged

    If TextBox1.Text <> "Enter Quantity" Then
        If TextBox2.Text <> "Enter SI Units" Then
            bttAddQUAtoDatabase.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged


    Dim charactersAllowed As String = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890^-*()."
    Dim Text As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim Letter As String
    Dim SelectionIndex As Integer = TextBox2.SelectionStart
    Dim Change As Integer




    Letter = TextBox2.Text.Substring(SelectionIndex - 1, 1)
    If Letter = "/" Then
        Text = Text.Replace(Letter, "^(-")
        SelectionIndex = SelectionIndex - 1
    End If



    Letter = TextBox2.Text.Substring(SelectionIndex - 1, 1)
    If charactersAllowed.Contains(Letter) = False Then
        Text = Text.Replace(Letter, String.Empty)
        Change = 1
    End If


    TextBox2.Text = Text
    TextBox2.Select(SelectionIndex - Change, 0)

    If TextBox1.Text <> "Enter Quantity" Then
        If cmbStateRateSumRatio.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            bttAddQUAtoDatabase.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Const AllowedChars = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890^-*()."

Private Sub TxtSIUnit_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSIUnit.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar >= " "c AndAlso Not AllowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub TxtSIUnit_KeyPress2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSIUnit.KeyPress
    Dim selectstart
    If e.KeyChar = "/" Then
        e.Handled = True
        selectstart = txtSIUnit.SelectionStart
        txtSIUnit.SelectedText = "*^-1"
        txtSIUnit.Select(selectstart + 1, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

I have solved the issue above using this code. Instead of using the `.textchanged` handle I have used `.keypress` which stopped the issue I was having previously. The text in the textbox was changing as the form was loading, leading to a problem with the start index of the text.  Using `.keypress` mean only user inputs let the code run, avoiding errors on loading.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.

There's a good candidate in your snippet for this exception:

```
Letter = TextBox1.Text.Substring(SelectionIndex - 1, 1)
```

You'll need to deal with the possibility that the textbox is empty or the SelectionStart property is 0.  Which will always bomb your code with "StartIndex cannot be less than zero".

Comment: I assume that CLR stands for Common Language Runtime. How would throwing these CLR exceptions affect debugging other code withing the project?

The textbox is set to have the contents "Enter SI Unit" in the form designer. Could I edit the code or my method of putting text into the box to begin with to avoid the error?

Comment: You misunderstand what the Thrown checkbox means.  Press F1 to get help.  You avoid the error by writing good code.  What you posted isn't good code, it is almost guarantee to fail.

Comment: I have fixed some errors in the code where the textbox tags where incorrect. I have now used the code `If TextBox2.Text = "Enter SI Units" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If`
 which seems to have solved the issue